# Bluetooth HDP Profile in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I know Bluetooth Health Device Profile is there in android after Android 4.0 ICS. Where our android mobile can act as sink & can talk to health devices (source) like ECG, Blood pressure monitor etc...
  My question is can we implement Bluetooth Health Device Profile between two Android mobiles. where one mobile can act as sink (receive data) & other mobile can act as source(send some dummy data)??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android does not support HDP in source mode.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. Note that I am pointing to Android API; HDP source role is probably included in BlueZ. It is just not acessible. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHealth.html