# Android Health Device Profile(HDP)

Tags: android

I know that the Bluetooth Health Device Profile already exist in Android after version 4.0 (ICS) which'll enable the devices to act as a Sink & talk to health devices (source) like ECG, Blood pressure monitor etc. However, my question is, can we implement a Bluetooth Health Device Profile on an Android mobile device that'll enable it to act as a Sink (receive data) & the other mobile device can act as source(send some dummy data)?

duplicate - [Bluetooth HDP Profile in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838311/bluetooth-hdp-profile-in-android)

Comment: Anyone would like to help me?